# Dont see anything inside my jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to create an UI.  After U moved everything to private and made getters and setters my `JFrame` is displaying blank.  For some reason I only see the basic grey window, but before that everything worked just fine.

```
public class Aboutus_GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel join;
    private JLabel Names;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Aboutus_GUI frame = new Aboutus_GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     */
    public Aboutus_GUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);     
        setTitle("About Us");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 727, 651);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);


        join = new JLabel();
        join.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/GUI_final/about_us.jpg"));
        join.setBounds(0, -267, 701, 770);
        contentPane.add(join);          

        Names = new JLabel();   
        Names.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/GUI_final/names.jpg"));
        Names.setLocation(10, 276);
        Names.setSize(887, 492);       
        contentPane.add(Names);
    }

    public JPanel getContentPane() {
        return contentPane;
    }

    public void setContentPane(JPanel contentPane) {
        this.contentPane = contentPane;
    }

    public JLabel getJoin() {
        return join;
    }

    public void setJoin(JLabel join) {
        this.join = join;
    }

    public JLabel getNames() {
        return Names;
    }

    public void setNames(JLabel names) {
        Names = names;
    }

}
```

Comment: Was one of your recent changes to add the getContentPane method?  I ask because that overrides a method in the JFrame class.  That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever actually add `contenetPane` to the frame. You just set it as a variable. As BPS commented, you prob dont want to override the `setContentPane` method. But, if you really do want to do that... Add

```
add(contentPane);
```

right after

```
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

I might also suggest using a `LayoutMager`. I suggest adding:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

as this will make the `contentPane` take up the whole frame.

Comment: Im getting this error                                                                                                
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Comment: I have a feeling its your setContentPane and getContentPane functions messing things up. I really do suggest you remove those. You are not going to lose functionality.